# WCF Authentication and Impersonation

Tags: asp.net, wcf, wcf-security, wcf-client

​Hi, I'm having some trouble implementing a WCF RoleService, well specifically the GetAllRolesForCurrentUser method. I can successfully connect to the service, but when I try and retrieve the roles for the user, it naturally uses current principal identity (i.e. the user under which the service is running). However, I need it for the user who has logged in.

I know that I have to pass the role service custom credentials (username/password) but how do you go about getting the service to impersonate that user.

Answer (score 0):

To implement impersonation in WCF service

1) Decorate the operation with OperationBehavior and give "Impersonation = ImpersonationOption.Required", as in the below code

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IHelloContract
{
    [OperationContract]
    string Hello(string message);
}

public class HelloService : IHelloService
{
    [OperationBehavior(Impersonation = ImpersonationOption.Required)]
    public string Hello(string message)
    {
        return "hello";
    }
}
```

2) Client side call it as below

```
  using (((WindowsIdentity)HttpContext.Current.User.Identity).Impersonate())
    {
        HelloService.ServiceClient myService = new HelloService.ServiceClient();
        Console.WriteLine(myService.Hello("How are you?"));
        myService.Close();
    }
```

Follow link for further reference : [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650591.aspx#_Step_7:_Impersonate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650591.aspx#_Step_7%3a_Impersonate)

Comment: That's technically the correct answer, however, the Authentication and Role Services dont allow you to decorate OperationalBehaviours as far as I'm aware.